# Multithreading in C# Visual Studio and receiving data from serialport connected to arduino

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I get an error saying that tbOutput can't be accessed on the thread?

I guess that it is something about it not being safely executed. How do i fix this error?

```
    private void DataReceivedHandler(
                object sender,
                SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.demoThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ThreadProcSafe));

        this.demoThread.Start();

        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        tbOutput.Text = indata;
    }

    private void ThreadProcSafe()
    {
        this.SetText("Something happened correctly");
    }

    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (this.tbOutput.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallBack d = new SetTextCallBack(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.tbOutput.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably get the error since your `DataReceivedHandler` gets called on non UI thread.
As stated in:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx (Remarks section)

If you are using .NET 4, you can do this: 
Instead of:

```
tbOutput.Text = indata
```

You should do:

```
tbOutput.Invoke(new Action(() => tbOutput.Text = indata));
```

And you do not need the extra thread